# Pass any Json Object in Query Params along with String

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, java-8

All,
I have my code as follows :

```
@POST(/test)
void test(@QueryParam("param1") String param1, @QueryParam("param2") String param2)
{
//some computations (converting param2 into bytes)
}
```

Here in param2 I want to pass a JSON. How can I do that , because when I am hitting API like

```
localhost:8080/test?param1=test&param2={---JSON-----}
```

It's showing: `400 BAD request`.

Can anyone please help me to pass JSON in the post request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Post request use body and Get request use address to pass info.

RestTemplate is easy way to use JSON with Spring.

Your controller should be something like:

```
@RestContoller
public class Controller {
        @Autowired
        private ApiService apiService; 
    
        @PostMapping("test")
        public FooDTO postApi(@Validated @RequestBody FooDTO foo) {
        return this.apiService.doSomethingWithFooAndReturn(foo);
        
        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to send json as a query param. Query params are not meant for sending large amounts of data.

However if you really need it, you will need to encode it in a format that does not clash with the URL scheme. Base64 might be a good choice for an encoding.